# JS, Menu button works, external link doesnt

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

```js
function transition() {
    var divtran = document.getElementById('mobile_menu');
    if (divtran.style.height == '100vh') 
       divtran.style.height = '0vh'
    else 
       divtran.style.height = '100vh'
}
```

```css
/*mobile Menu */

.mobilemenu{
 z-index: 21;
 margin-top: -80px;
 margin-right: -7px;
 position:relative;
 width:50px;
 height:40px;
 border: 0px;
 -webkit-transition:background .3s;
 transition:background .3s
}

.mobilemenu span{
 height:-2px;
 top:20px;
 left:10px;
 right:10px;
 position:absolute;
}

.mobilemenu span::after,.mobilemenu span::before{
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 height: 3px;
 width:100%;
 border-radius: 50px;
 background-color: #232323;
 content:"";
}

.mobilemenu_transition {
 background-color: transparent;
}

/*transition code persec*/
.mobilemenu_transition span{
 -webkit-transition:background 0s .3s;
 transition:background 0s .3s;
}

.mobilemenu_transition span::after,.mobilemenu_transition span::before{
 -webkit-transition-duration:.3s,.3s;
 transition-duration:.3s,.3s;
 -webkit-transition-delay:.3s,0s;
 transition-delay:.3s,0s;
}

.mobilemenu_transition span::before{
 -webkit-transition-property:top,-webkit-transform;
 transition-property:top,transform;
}

.mobilemenu_transition span::after{
 -webkit-transition-property:bottom,-webkit-transform;
 transition-property:bottom,transform;
}

.mobilemenu_transition.act{
 background-color: transparent;
}

.mobilemenu_transition.act span::before{
 -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
 -ms-transform:rotate(45deg);
 transform:rotate(45deg);
}

.mobilemenu_transition.act span::after{
 -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
 -ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);
 transform:rotate(-45deg);
}

#mobile_menu {
 width: 100%;
 height: 0vh;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 18;
 background-color: orange;
 overflow: hidden; 
 position: fixed;
 background-color: #f3f3f3;
 
 -webkit-transition-duration:.3s,.3s;
 transition-duration:.3s,.3s;
 -webkit-transition-delay:.3s,0s;
 transition-delay:.3s,0s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="mobile_menu">
  <br /><br /><br /><a href="#" onclick="transition()">bottom</a>
 </div> 
 <a href="#"><div class="_menu"><button onClick = "transition()" class="mobilemenu mobilemenu_transition"><span></span></button>
 </div></a>
                
<script>
  (function() {
    "use strict";
    var toggles = document.querySelectorAll(".mobilemenu");
    for (var i = toggles.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      var toggle = toggles[i];
      toggleHandler(toggle);
    };

    function toggleHandler(toggle) {
      toggle.addEventListener( "click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        (this.classList.contains("act") === true) ? this.classList.remove("act") : this.classList.add("act");
      });
    }

  })();
</script>
   
  
</body>
</html>
```

https://github.com/Arxhtects/Css_menu_onepage

link above to the menu code. I cant seem to work out how to get an external link to not only close the menu div that appears after you have clicked the line but also remove the menu class "act" so that the animation reverts to its original state.

getting an external link to close the menu div that appears is easy. But I cant seem to make it remove the class "act" that the menu button does.

so basically it leaves the X there once you click on the link. I appreciate any help at all. thank you in advance :)

I'm sorry if I'm being vague, but can anyone help?

Comment: are u having multiple elements with class mobilemenu?

Comment: Why is there a `<div>` and a `<button>` element element inside an anchor (that `<a>`) element? You may be happy that the browser's DOM parser (that reads those structures) doesn't complain a lot...

Comment: I'm not going to lie I've only just noticed that I've wrapped div and button in an anchor and I'm not ensure why. There must be a reason...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function transition() {
       var divtran = document.getElementById('mobile_menu');
       var mobileMenu = document.querySelectorAll(".mobilemenu");
       var menuOpen = false;
       if (divtran.style.height == '100vh') {
           divtran.style.height = '0vh';
           menuOpen = false;
       }
       else {
           divtran.style.height = '100vh'
           menuOpen = true;
       }
       for(var i=0;i<mobileMenu.length;i++){
          if(menuOpen) {
            mobileMenu[i].classList.add("act");
          }
          else {
            mobileMenu[i].classList.remove("act");
          }

       }
}
```

```css
/*mobile Menu */

.mobilemenu{
 z-index: 21;
 margin-top: -80px;
 margin-right: -7px;
 position:relative;
 width:50px;
 height:40px;
 border: 0px;
 -webkit-transition:background .3s;
 transition:background .3s
}


.mobilemenu span{
 height:-2px;
 top:20px;
 left:10px;
 right:10px;
 position:absolute;
}

.mobilemenu span::after,.mobilemenu span::before{
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 height: 3px;
 width:100%;
 border-radius: 50px;
 background-color: #232323;
 content:"";
}


.mobilemenu_transition {
 background-color: transparent;
}

/*transition code persec*/
.mobilemenu_transition span{
 -webkit-transition:background 0s .3s;
 transition:background 0s .3s;
}

.mobilemenu_transition span::after,.mobilemenu_transition span::before{
 -webkit-transition-duration:.3s,.3s;
 transition-duration:.3s,.3s;
 -webkit-transition-delay:.3s,0s;
 transition-delay:.3s,0s;
}

.mobilemenu_transition span::before{
 -webkit-transition-property:top,-webkit-transform;
 transition-property:top,transform;
}

.mobilemenu_transition span::after{
 -webkit-transition-property:bottom,-webkit-transform;
 transition-property:bottom,transform;
}

.mobilemenu_transition.act{
 background-color: transparent;
}

.mobilemenu_transition.act span::before{
 -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
 -ms-transform:rotate(45deg);
 transform:rotate(45deg);
}

.mobilemenu_transition.act span::after{
 -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
 -ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);
 transform:rotate(-45deg);
}


#mobile_menu {
 width: 100%;
 height: 0vh;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 18;
 background-color: orange;
 overflow: hidden; 
 position: fixed;
 background-color: #f3f3f3;
 
 -webkit-transition-duration:.3s,.3s;
 transition-duration:.3s,.3s;
 -webkit-transition-delay:.3s,0s;
 transition-delay:.3s,0s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="mobile_menu">
   <br /><br /><br /><a href="#" onclick="transition()">bottom</a>
  </div> 
   <a href="#"><div class="_menu"><button onClick = "transition()" class="mobilemenu mobilemenu_transition"><span></span></button>
   </div></a>
   
   
   
   
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, please don't forget to provide explanations to what you did to answer on the OP's question. It would help him to figure out what's the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your time! Its a much better way of looking at the code than I was. I understanf what he's done thank you very much.

Comment: upvote if the solution worked so others can also find it helpful